# Regex solution for data removal within R

Tags: r

I'm trying to clean data. I came across to two things I cannot find solution to:

I have vector of characters as following:

```
"4353545 Here comes sentence."
"and now one more"
```

I would like to replace both with empty string. I have tried for the first one:

```
gsub("\\^[0-9].*","",dataframe$column)  # if it starts with number replace with empty string
```

for the second one:

```
gsub("\\^[a-z].*","",dataframe$column) # when it starts with letter instead of number = empty string
```

It works however in this case:

```
"! andn now one more"

gsub("\\!.*","",dataframe$column) # here this solution works; it starts with excl. and its replaced with empty string
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be escaping the `^` anchor - by doing so you are making it part of your search expression. What about something like this: `gsub("^[0-9a-z]+.*","",dataframe$column)`; or @Richard Scriven's answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the regular expression `^[0-9a-z](.*)` to match strings beginning with either a number or a lower-case letter.  Then instead of `gsub`, which looks for all matches, use `sub` since you only want the first match.

```
> ( x <- c("4353545 Here comes sentence.", "and now one more",  
           "! andn now one more") )
# [1] "4353545 Here comes sentence." "and now one more"    
# [3] "! andn now one more"         
> sub("^[0-9a-z](.*)", "", x) 
# [1] ""                    ""                    "! andn now one more"
```

Note:  As nrussell points out, you should not escape the `^` when it denotes the beginning of the string.  For the beginning of the string, just use `^` as-is.